# View SQL's errorlog in Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

Is there a way to view the SQL Server errorlogs in Amazon's RDS?  I usually use sp_ReadErrorlog, but in RDS we need to be a member of securityadmin role.

Comment: The more I use SQL Server on RDS, the less I like it.  So many features are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.SQLServer.html), there's a custom stored procedure that does just that:

```
EXEC rdsadmin.dbo.rds_read_error_log [index]
```